# Replacing commas with spaces for classes in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am using product tags as a way to filter what users see depending on if they are commercial or consumer customers. I have managed to get the tags into the class of each product displayed in a collection using the following code. The {{itemTags}} is being used to pass the value over into the HTML.

```
itemHtml = itemHtml.replace(/{{itemTags}}/g, data.tags);

<div class="{{itemTags}}">
```

The only issue is that all of the tags are displayed in a string with no spaces and commas in between each one. Resulting in the following class being added as an example.

```
class="accessories,Consumer,DJI Air 2S,live,pre-order,preorder"
```

Is it possible to remove the commas and add spaces in between each tag?

Comment: `itemHtml = itemHtml.replace(/{{itemTags}}/g, data.tags);` is this JS code?

Comment: Are you trying to use liquid or js\, not cleared?

Comment: @Onkar JS with the Shopify API I think. An example of the file can be found here on GitHub - [link] (https://gist.github.com/keyurshah/029e0c967d97ae76e8bf118cb2dcc975)

Answer (score 1):

use the [replace](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/replace/) tag in liquid

itemHtml = itemHtml.replace(/{{itemTags | replace: "," , " " }}/g, data.tags);

Comment: How would this look with `itemHtml = itemHtml.replace(/{{itemTags}}/g, data.tags);` as I have to do this to get the data.tags into the product template.